# Store grid rowcount in ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik-grid

I'm implementing MVVM for a WPF application.
The ViewModels are created as follows:

- ViewModel: base class from which all ViewModels override
- MainTemplateViewModel: the 'Masterpage' ViewModel which contains a ViewModel property `Current` that contains the ViewModel to show
- CustomerOverviewViewModel: an example of a view that can be placed in the `MainTemplateViewModel.Current`

The CustomerGridViewModel contains a Telerik GridView. I would like to show the number of items in the title of the MainTemplateViewModel. The `GridView.Items.Count` property implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` so I would like to bind this property to `ViewModel.RowCount` (because the CustomerGridViewModel doesn't know it is part of the MainTemplateViewModel it cannot be bound directly to the TextBlock). I can in turn use `ViewModel.NumberOfRecords` to show the amount in the title.

How can I bind the Count property to a property in my ViewModel?

**Edit**

I'll describe the issue in more detail:

The list of objects shown in the grid is a binding from the ViewModel:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="CustomerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerViewModels}">    
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

When filtering the Grid in memory, the Telerik Grid automatically changes the `GridView.Items.Count` property (this does not mean the original list count is changed!). So if I can bind this property to a property in the ViewModel class, this would solve the problem.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int numberOfRecords;

    public int NumberOfRecords
    {
        get { return numberOfRecords; }
        set { numberOfRecords = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

**MainTemplateViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainTemplateViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ViewModel current = new MainOverviewViewModel();

    public ViewModel Current
    {
        get { return current; }
        set
        {
            if (current != value)
            {
                current = value; OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomerOverview.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class CustomerOverview : UserControl
{
    public CustomerOverview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CustomerGrid.Items.CollectionChanged += ItemsCollectionChanged;
        this.CustomerGrid.Loaded += CustomerGrid_Loaded;
    }

    void CustomerGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* METHOD 1 PROBLEM: the field to bind to in the MainTemplate is out of scope and accessing a view is not MVVM */
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Items.Count");
        binding.Source = CustomerGrid;
        ((MainWindow)this.ParentOfType<MainWindow>()).NumberOfRecords.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
    }


    void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* METHOD 2 PROBLEM: codebehind code should be in viewmodel */
        ((CustomerOverviewViewModel)this.DataContext).NumberOfRecords = CustomerGrid.Items.Count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the data in your `UserControl`, just declare a `DependencyProperty` of the relevant type in it. You can then load the data in the main view model and simply data bind to it from the `UserControl`. You could do something like this simple example:

In `CustomerOverview.xaml.cs`:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<YourDataType>), typeof(CustomerOverview), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

...

In `CustomerOverview.xaml`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
    x:Type YourPrefix:CustomerOverview}}}" ... />
```

...

In `MainWindow.xaml` (or whichever relevant view):

```
<YourPrefix:CustomerOverview 
    Items="{Binding SomeCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel}" ... />
```

...

In `MainTemplateViewModel.cs` (or whichever relevant view model):

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> SomeCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel
{
    get { return someCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel; }
    set
    {
        someCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel"); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfRecords"); 
    }
}

public int NumberOfRecords
{
    get { return someCollectionPropertyInMainTemplateViewModel.Count; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do see two issues: first, there will be multiple grids so I would like to have the logic to fill the grids on the respective viewmodel (instead of all in the parent). The second issue is that the grid items are filtered in memory and the only correct count is GridView.Items.Count property. I've explained this in an edit in the original post.

Comment: Then make your `DependencyProperty` expose the `Count` value from the `UserControl` and data bind to it from the main view.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you want your master to show details of the child.

Your master should be able to know your child by your Current property.
If you are using MVVM correctly, the data bound to your grid comes from the child-ViewModel.

In that case, you have already have the itemscount in your child-ViewModel.

After this you can say in your Master something like

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Current.NumberOfRows}"></Label>
```

According to [this page](http://www.telerik.com/forums/accessing-the-filtered-collection-through-mvvm-after-applying-filter-to-the-wpf-radgridview) you could wrap your source in a QueryableCollectionView

Comment: This is entirely correct but the issue is getting the number of visible rows in the Current.NumberOfRows property. The number of visible rows can be changed in memory by filtering the Telerik Grid (which changes the GridView.Items.Count property). I've made an Edit to the original post explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Grid has two properties

Visible Count

```
TelerikGrid.Items.Count
```

Total Count

```
TelerikGrid.Items.TotalItemCount
```

In case this helps!